# Getting driving speed in an Android app

Tags: android

How can I develop a program in android to view the speed of the android holder ?

I need to develop a program that determine location and the speed of the android mobile holder if he drive.now I know how to determine the current location of the android mobile holder but i don't know how can i determine his speed . I hope it clear now

Comment: The question is really not clear? what speed, are you talking about physical speed, and hence want to measure differences between positions over time? or something else? And do you really intend people to tell you exactly point by point how to do it? They might as well do it themselves. Try finding particular problems you want help with.

Comment: Fundamental physics says it's not possible until you define a frame of reference. Speed relative to what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace android.location contains a lot of useful classes. Basically what you need is to use `Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)` and then with `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` you can subscribe to listen location updates for a provider. To determine the speed you need to listen the `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`. From a `Location` you can call `getSpeed()`. Of course determining the speed needs a proper amount of satellite fixes so a given Location result may not always contain the speed nor bearing.